# ubuntu 14.04 wont boot after installation

Tags: 14.04, boot, software-installation, reboot

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 
After the installation it won´t boot and I done the boot-repair in Ubuntu and I Think I have the right boot-setting in BOIS. It will directly go to the windows OS. 
After the boot-repair it send me this:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12141501
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the Ubuntu's EFI entry in BIOS. Search for boot options (in some machines ESC key needs to be continuously pressed after the power button, but it varies from machine to machine).